# SparkLauncher : App args are treated as Unrecognized Option

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-launcher

I am using SparkLauncher to submit a spark application from code.

```
        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>();
        env.put("SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND", "1");

        System.out.println("Creating SparkLauncher");
        SparkLauncher launcher = new SparkLauncher(env);
        launcher.setSparkHome(sparkHome);
        launcher.setAppResource(appResource);
        launcher.setMaster(sparkMaster);
        launcher.setMainClass(mainClass);
        launcher.setAppName("TestFromJersey")
        .setVerbose(true)
        .setConf("spark.cores.max", "20")
        .setConf("spark.executor.memory", "30G")
        .setConf("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:ConcGCThreads=13 -XX:NewRatio=1 -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution");

        for(File f : new File("/home/user/jars").listFiles()){
            launcher.addJar(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Launching Spark Job from SparkLauncher");
            launcher.addAppArgs("--jobName myJobName",
                    "--time "+System.currentTimeMillis()+"",
                    "--authUser admin",
                    "--savePage true");
            launcher.startApplication(new SparkAppHandle.Listener() {
                   @Override public void stateChanged(SparkAppHandle h) { 
                       System.out.println("App State:" + h.getState());
                   }
                   @Override public void infoChanged(SparkAppHandle h) { } 
                  });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("error in launching Spark Application");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now, the job doesn't run at all, and the handler functions are not called, which I believe is because of error in job configuration. in the output log i can see the following error :

```
org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException: Unrecognized option: -jobName myJobName
```

So, it seems to me that the code is not able to recognize appArgs separately from sparkArguments.

Any pointers? is the format i am using for adding AppArgs correct ?

Comment: Can you try for this `"--jobName=myJobName"`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with some hit and trial, the correct way to specify arguments is:

```
launcher.addAppArgs("--jobName","myJobName",
                    "--authUser","admin",
                    "--savePage","true");
```